# Why has Hussain Haqqani become a strong opposer of Pakistan?

Tags: pakistan

According to [www.husainhaqqani.com](http://www.husainhaqqani.com)

> Husain Haqqani is former Ambassador of Pakistan to the United States
>   (2008–2011). He is currently Senior Fellow and Director for South and
>   Central Asia at the Hudson Institute and co-edits the journal ‘Current
>   Trends in Islamist Ideology’ published by Hudson Institute’s Center
>   for Islam, Democracy, and Future of the Muslim World.

Hussain Haqqani is the main actor of [**Memogate scandal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memogate_(Pakistan)).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memogate_(Pakistan)),

> On 12 June the supreme court commission released its findings and
>   found that after testimony by all parties and verifying the forensic
>   results of Ijaz's BlackBerry conversations with Haqqani it was
>   "incontrovertibly established" that Husain Haqqani had written the
>   memo and was being called back to Pakistan to face likely charges of
>   treason.

Secondly, his recent [writings](http://www.financialexpress.com/industry/india-vs-pakistan-why-cant-we-just-be-friends-by-husain-haqqani-book-review/352948/) suggest that he has a deep grudge on the state.

My question is, **being one of the most prolific and senior Pakistani diplomats, what made him commit such an act?**

Comment: From the Wikipedia page: `ostensibly seeking help of the Obama administration in the wake of the Osama bin Laden raid to avert a military takeover of the civilian government in Pakistan, as well as assisting in a civilian takeover of the government and military apparatus`. You may agree or disagree, but certainly there are important reasons here... Why are you dismissing the "he wanted a civilian government" reason?

Comment: I might be wrong, but AFAIK in Pakistan the military seems to have, how to express it, an "important degree of influence" over the government. You claim that "the army chief never had any such ambition", but in 2011 the last military takeover had ended three years before... Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_coups_in_Pakistan can help explain Mr. Haqqani fears.

Comment: @SJuan76, clearly, you don't know the context of the stepping down of Gen. Musharraf, and the scenario of 2008. Secondly, if you think you are right, then, why weren't more people like Husain Haqqani before 2011?

Comment: @anonymous Even when Musharraf stepped down, Military did not give up their influence. They sent off Musharraf with a guard of honor, effectively sending the message to civilians that they had his back. This is one of the main reasons why article 58-2b hasn't been invoked against Musharraf, which could result in him hanging for constitutional violations, designed specifically to avoid martial laws (But evidently failed as Politicians dont have the guts to invoke it). In same PPP govt, it was Gen. Kiyani who influenced the government during long march troubles.

Comment: @anonymous Also there have always been bureaucrats and politicians who resent military's meddling in the politics, especially since their meddling has almost always lead the country from one disaster to another (65 war and Pakistan losing technical edge over india, 71 war and Bangladesh separating, Animosity against USSR, Kalashnikov culture, Jihadism, Wahabbism, Sectarian Violence etc). Military has however a strong grip over people and the critics are either violently removed from the stage or defamed widely by ISI.

Comment: @NSNoob, `... especially since their meddling has almost always lead the country from one disaster to another ...` - I don'r fully agree. Your points require detailed discussions. Civil and military are equally responsible. The failure was due to immaturity of Pakistan as a nation, so to speak.

Comment: @anonymous I beg to differ. When were the civilians afforded to work without military's interference since Ghulam Muhammad introduced General Iskander Mirza and General Ayub Khan to power?  "Immaturity of Pakistan" is an absurd argument, I am sorry. India was just as immature as Pakistan, both nations won independence together and yet their military never did what Pakistani military did. They remained loyal to their duties unlike Pakistani military

Comment: @NSNoob, so, who is going to save PK from BJP + RSS aggression if you want to dismantle military's influence since people like Nawaz, Mir Ayaz Sadiq, Achakzai, Fazlur Rahman, Mohsin Dawar, Gulalai Ismail, Ali Wazir, Manzur Pashtin, etc. are proven to be Indian stooges? Nawaz was responsible for 1999 Kargil defeat AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't take much research to see why Hussain Haqqani has a dislike for Pakistan due to his kidnapping and being roughed up for a couple months while being detained. It seems this alone would be enough for any normal person to dislike such a country that allows their jail system to treat people so inhumane.

Additionally, as in the second paragraph of the [early life and career](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husain_Haqqani#Early_life_and_career) section of the below referenced post, he worked as a journalist for 8 years covering the [war in Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet%E2%80%93Afghan_War). It can be deduced that his time [during this time frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet%E2%80%93Afghan_War#1980s:_Insurrection) that his perspective here may have some influence on why he'd later have a dislike for Pakistan.

> **Relationship with Pakistan's Military**
>
> Husain Haqqani has long had a difficult relationship with Pakistan's
> military. Haqqani had made enemies among some in Pakistan's military
> due to his criticism of the
> Army.[<sup>[36]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husain_Haqqani#cite_note-36)[<sup>[37]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husain_Haqqani#cite_note-37)
> In 1999, he was kidnapped by Pakistani intelligence agents who roughed
> him up and held him for two months until a court ordered his
> release.[<sup>[38]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husain_Haqqani#cite_note-38)
> The ISI tried to stop Haqqani from being appointed Ambassador to the
> United States, and kept him under regular surveillance during his
> tenure due to his criticism of the
> military.[<sup>[2]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husain_Haqqani#cite_note-democracy-2)
>
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husain_Haqqani#Relationship_with_Pakistan%27s_Military)

Furthermore, based on his early life and career studies in Pakistan college, he spent a lot of time reading about American history. So it seems he may have had influence of the history of America and the American ideologies at play compared to what he understood about current events and/or history of Pakistan.

> **Early life and career**
>
> He frequently visited the library at the US consulate, reading volumes
> of American history. Later, when students wanted to attack the
> consulate as part of a protest against the United States, Haqqani
> refused.[<sup>[9]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husain_Haqqani#cite_note-9)
> Haqqani received a B.A. degree with distinction in 1977 and a MA
> degree in International Relations in 1980 from the [University of
> Karachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Karachi).
>
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husain_Haqqani#Early_life_and_career)